# Can NSDocument work with files on webdav server?

Tags: cocoa, webdav

I have a requirement to extend an existing Cocoa Document-based application to support reading and writing files hosted on a Webdav server. The plan is to register a custom URI in the application plist so that a webapp will be able to launch our application with a link from a web browser.

The problem is that NSDocument only seems to support URLs for physical files, whether they are on a local disk or some network drive mounted on the system. On Windows it will treat a webdav URL the same as a local file but this doesn't seem to be the case on Mac with Cocoa. We need to be able to make this work without having to mount the webdav folder on the local machine.

Have I got this right? Or am I missing something obvious?

If I was to extend NSDocument to work with a webdav hosted file (Or a file accessed through some other API) how might I go about this?